# A problem about an algebraic number

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> Show that $2^{\frac{1}{2}}+5^{\frac{1}{3}}$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$ of degree $6$.

Can I just construct $x=2^{\frac{1}{2}}+5^{\frac{1}{3}}$, 
$x-2^{\frac{1}{2}}=5^{\frac{1}{3}}$, 
$x^3-3*2^{\frac{1}{2}}x^2+6x-2\frac{1}{2}=5$,
$x^3+6x-5=\sqrt{2}(3x^2+2)$,
$(x^3+6x-5)^2=2(3x^2+2)^2$,
$x^6+12x^4-10x^3+36x^2-60x+25=18x^4+24x^2+8$,
$x^6-6x^4-10x^3+12x^2-60x+17=0$.

Does it show what is required?

Then, $2^{\frac{1}{2}}+5^{\frac{1}{3}}$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$ of degree 6.

Comment: yes it is right

Comment: @learnmore correct me if I'm wrong, but this proof only shows that $x$ is algebraic, not necessarily that the degree is 6? I believe this only shows that the degree is *at most* 6.

Comment: I believe "an element is said algebraic of degree 6" if there exists a  polynomial of degree 6 of which it is a root @Nico

Comment: you can ask for clarification of the above definition from OP @Nico

Comment: @learnmore An element is algebraic of degree 6 if there is an **irreducible** polynomial of degree 6 of which it is a root.

Comment: Hi everyone, so what can I do for the degree 6?